# How to require Node.js module?

Tags: node.js, npm, webassembly

The [MDN guide on compiling Rust to WASM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Rust_to_wasm) makes the following statement:

> This imports our module from the node_modules folder. This isn't considered a best practice, but this is a demo, so we'll work with it for now.

Which is in reference to this code snippet:

```
const js = import("./node_modules/@yournpmusername/hello-wasm/hello_wasm.js");
```

What is the "best practice" for importing the *hello-wasm* module?

---

I did try what I thought would work, as it's how you import other installed modules, but it didn't work:

```
const js = require("hello-wasm");
```

This gave a module not found error.  Note that the *node_modules* did include the *hello-wasm* directory, put there by npm.

---

Adding `"main": "hello_wasm.js"` to `package.json` in the `hello_wasm` package causes the following error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
/home/vinnie/electron-wasm/node_modules/hello-wasm/hello_wasm.js:2
import * as wasm from './hello_wasm_bg';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Comment: Does `hello-wasm` has a `package.json` file which define the main file to be reffered to? (in your case `hello-wasm/hello_wasm.js`)

Comment: It did not, as `package.json` was automatically generated by `wasm-pack build`.  I added `"main": "hello_wasm.js"` to the file and it gave me a different error (I'll add it to my question)

Comment: After your edit - it seems like a different problem now. Try maybe `import * as wasm from '/hello_wasm_bg'` (without the dot)

Comment: ah sorry I left out an important part of the error: it was `Unexpected token *`

Comment: This question does not seem to involve enough of Rust to merit the [tag:rust] tag, so I removed it. Feel free to put it again in the event that you need to add Rust code for an appropriate MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't import because the correct package name is `@yournpmusername/hello-wasm` and not `hello-wasm`. You might want to take a look at the `package.json` file.

I guess the "best practice" would be the same practice most people do when they import a external dependency in a synchronous manner, i.e., writing `import { foo, bar } from 'wasm-module-example'` but there is a problem, this behavior is going to depend on the bundler you are using.

`Parcel` makes it easy to [import wasm modules](https://parceljs.org/webAssembly.html) and `webpack`, the bundler used in the MDN guide, has some somes [caveats](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6615) so currently it is best to import asynchronously instead of synchronously.

```
import('@yournpmusername/hello-wasm').then(wasm => wasm.some_function()).catch(console.error);
```